# Dissolve/combine an Array based on attributes

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array that i made by combining two other arrays. The new array has all the data from the original arrays joined based on an attribute (id). I would like to make a new array that combines all the attribute (id)values into one string without duplicating the data. The data has many different (Attribute and AttributeValue) pairs but the rest of the data is the same. here is a two examples of the data that come out:

```
    0:
    id: "00ABCD-0003"
    AccessionID: "UWAR_007_Test"
    Attribute: "Object Type"
    AttributeValue: "Glass"
    BoxNumber: "2000"
    CatalogDate: null
    Cataloger: "rkirkwo2@uwyo.edu"
    FSNumber: null
    FreeformValue: null
    ProjectNumber: "#154 WAPA"
    SiteID: "00ABCD"
    Units: null

    1:
    id: "00ABCD-0003"
    AccessionID: "UWAR_007_Test"
    Attribute: "Glass Material Type"
    AttributeValue: "Aluminosilicate glass"
    BoxNumber: "2000"
    CatalogDate: null
    Cataloger: "rkirkwo2@uwyo.edu"
    FSNumber: null
    FreeformValue: null
    ProjectNumber: "#154 WAPA"
    SiteID: "00ABCD"
    Units: null
```

below if the full array of data. Thanks for any help!

The data will be used to print out tags for a museum to put into bags that the artifacts will be stored in. So i need all the data i can get without duplicating anything.

```
    listArray =[{"id":"00ABCD-0003","SiteID":"00ABCD","AccessionID":"UWAR_007_Test","ProjectNumber":"#154 WAPA","FSNumber":null,"BoxNumber":"2000","ArtifactCount":null,"Cataloger":"rkirkwo2@uwyo.edu","CatalogDate":null,"ArtifactNotes":null,"Attribute":"Object Type","AttributeValue":"Glass","FreeformValue":null,"Units":null},{"id":"00ABCD-0003","SiteID":"00ABCD","AccessionID":"UWAR_007_Test","ProjectNumber":"#154 WAPA","FSNumber":null,"BoxNumber":"2000","ArtifactCount":null,"Cataloger":"rkirkwo2@uwyo.edu","CatalogDate":null,"ArtifactNotes":null,"Attribute":"Glass Material Type","AttributeValue":"Aluminosilicate glass","FreeformValue":null,"Units":null},{"id":"00ABCD-0003","SiteID":"00ABCD","AccessionID":"UWAR_007_Test","ProjectNumber":"#154 WAPA","FSNumber":null,"BoxNumber":"2000","ArtifactCount":null,"Cataloger":"rkirkwo2@uwyo.edu","CatalogDate":null,"ArtifactNotes":null,"Attribute":"Color","AttributeValue":"Brown","FreeformValue":null,"Units":null},{"id":"00ABCD-0003","SiteID":"00ABCD","AccessionID":"UWAR_007_Test","ProjectNumber":"#154 WAPA","FSNumber":null,"BoxNumber":"2000","ArtifactCount":null,"Cataloger":"rkirkwo2@uwyo.edu","CatalogDate":null,"ArtifactNotes":null,"Attribute":"Glass Object Type","AttributeValue":"Bead","FreeformValue":null,"Units":null},{"id":"00ABCD-0001","SiteID":"00ABCD","AccessionID":"UWAR_007_Test","ProjectNumber":"#154 WAPA","FSNumber":"f2","BoxNumber":"1000","ArtifactCount":null,"Cataloger":"rkirkwo2@uwyo.edu","CatalogDate":null,"ArtifactNotes":null,"Attribute":"Datum ID (if known)","AttributeValue":null,"FreeformValue":"NAD83","Units":null},{"id":"00ABCD-0001","SiteID":"00ABCD","AccessionID":"UWAR_007_Test","ProjectNumber":"#154 WAPA","FSNumber":"f2","BoxNumber":"1000","ArtifactCount":null,"Cataloger":"rkirkwo2@uwyo.edu","CatalogDate":null,"ArtifactNotes":null,"Attribute":"Object Type","AttributeValue":"Concrete","FreeformValue":null,"Units":null},{"id":"00ABCD-0001","SiteID":"00ABCD","AccessionID":"UWAR_007_Test","ProjectNumber":"#154 WAPA","FSNumber":"f2","BoxNumber":"1000","ArtifactCount":null,"Cataloger":"rkirkwo2@uwyo.edu","CatalogDate":null,"ArtifactNotes":null,"Attribute":"Concrete Object Type","AttributeValue":"General Building Material","FreeformValue":null,"Units":null},{"id":"00ABCD-0001","SiteID":"00ABCD","AccessionID":"UWAR_007_Test","ProjectNumber":"#154 WAPA","FSNumber":"f2","BoxNumber":"1000","ArtifactCount":null,"Cataloger":"rkirkwo2@uwyo.edu","CatalogDate":null,"ArtifactNotes":null,"Attribute":"Concrete Material Type","AttributeValue":"Cellular concrete","FreeformValue":null,"Units":null},{"id":"00ABCD-0001","SiteID":"00ABCD","AccessionID":"UWAR_007_Test","ProjectNumber":"#154 WAPA","FSNumber":"f2","BoxNumber":"1000","ArtifactCount":null,"Cataloger":"rkirkwo2@uwyo.edu","CatalogDate":null,"ArtifactNotes":null,"Attribute":"Provenience","AttributeValue":"Surface Collection","FreeformValue":null,"Units":null},{"id":"00ABCD-0001","SiteID":"00ABCD","AccessionID":"UWAR_007_Test","ProjectNumber":"#154 WAPA","FSNumber":"f2","BoxNumber":"1000","ArtifactCount":null,"Cataloger":"rkirkwo2@uwyo.edu","CatalogDate":null,"ArtifactNotes":null,"Attribute":"Datum Location","AttributeValue":"UTMs","FreeformValue":null,"Units":null},{"id":"00ABCD-0001","SiteID":"00ABCD","AccessionID":"UWAR_007_Test","ProjectNumber":"#154 WAPA","FSNumber":"f2","BoxNumber":"1000","ArtifactCount":null,"Cataloger":"rkirkwo2@uwyo.edu","CatalogDate":null,"ArtifactNotes":null,"Attribute":"UTM Zone","AttributeValue":"12N","FreeformValue":null,"Units":null},{"id":"00ABCD-0002","SiteID":"00ABCD","AccessionID":"UWAR_010_Test","ProjectNumber":"#154 WAPA","FSNumber":null,"BoxNumber":null,"ArtifactCount":null,"Cataloger":"rkirkwo2@uwyo.edu","CatalogDate":null,"ArtifactNotes":null,"Attribute":"Object Type","AttributeValue":"Metal","FreeformValue":null,"Units":null},{"id":"00ABCD-0002","SiteID":"00ABCD","AccessionID":"UWAR_010_Test","ProjectNumber":"#154 WAPA","FSNumber":null,"BoxNumber":null,"ArtifactCount":null,"Cataloger":"rkirkwo2@uwyo.edu","CatalogDate":null,"ArtifactNotes":null,"Attribute":"Metal Material Type","AttributeValue":"Brass","FreeformValue":null,"Units":null},{"id":"00ABCD-0002","SiteID":"00ABCD","AccessionID":"UWAR_010_Test","ProjectNumber":"#154 WAPA","FSNumber":null,"BoxNumber":null,"ArtifactCount":null,"Cataloger":"rkirkwo2@uwyo.edu","CatalogDate":null,"ArtifactNotes":null,"Attribute":"Metal Object Type","AttributeValue":"Axe","FreeformValue":null,"Units":null},{"id":"00ABCD-0004","SiteID":"00ABCD","AccessionID":"UWAR-125-2019-14","ProjectNumber":"#190","FSNumber":null,"BoxNumber":null,"ArtifactCount":null,"Cataloger":"rkirkwo2@uwyo.edu","CatalogDate":null,"ArtifactNotes":null,"Attribute":"Object Type","AttributeValue":"Rubber","FreeformValue":null,"Units":null},{"id":"00ABCD-0004","SiteID":"00ABCD","AccessionID":"UWAR-125-2019-14","ProjectNumber":"#190","FSNumber":null,"BoxNumber":null,"ArtifactCount":null,"Cataloger":"rkirkwo2@uwyo.edu","CatalogDate":null,"ArtifactNotes":null,"Attribute":"Rubber Object Type","AttributeValue":"Tire","FreeformValue":null,"Units":null},{"id":"00ABCD-0004","SiteID":"00ABCD","AccessionID":"UWAR-125-2019-14","ProjectNumber":"#190","FSNumber":null,"BoxNumber":null,"ArtifactCount":null,"Cataloger":"rkirkwo2@uwyo.edu","CatalogDate":null,"ArtifactNotes":null,"Attribute":"Rubber Material Type","AttributeValue":"Natural Rubber","FreeformValue":null,"Units":null}]
```

For example, I would like to see:

```
    id: "00ABCD-0003"
    AccessionID: "UWAR_007_Test"
    Attribute: "Object Type"
    AttributeValue: "Glass"
    Attribute: "Glass Material Type"
    AttributeValue: "Aluminosilicate glass"
    BoxNumber: "2000"
    CatalogDate: null
    Cataloger: "rkirkwo2@uwyo.edu"
    FSNumber: null
    FreeformValue: null
    ProjectNumber: "#154 WAPA"
    SiteID: "00ABCD"
    Units: null
```

Answer (score 0):

In that case you need to filter your array with distinct ID.

Check out this post

https://codeburst.io/javascript-array-distinct-5edc93501dc4

Comment: This doesn't seem to work the way i need it to. when i tried it out on just one id in the array (to  make it shorter for testing) it auto incremented my id's